# having different dropdown value when calling through URL

Tags: url, drop-down-menu, parameters, powerbi

I'm trying to read data with Power BI from Web. However, my problem is when I read this website:
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-au/pricing/details/sql-database/single/

I have preselected West-US as region.
How do I select "Australia-East" by adding some parameters to the url when I want to load the URL from Power BI? Thanks.

Comment: The different information is shown/hidden via javascript, not URL parameters.

Comment: so basically I cant add something to my url that brings up "australia East" as dropdown?

Comment: No, unfortunately. You see that the URL does not change when you select values in the dropdowns. This is all triggered by Javascript. There may be a way to access the unfiltered data, but it's not with URL parameters.